# How I know which URL are in use at starts_url (Scrapy)?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm building a Scrapy that crawling under two pages (e.x: PageDucky, PageHorse), and I pass that two pages in a starts_url field.
But for pagination, I need to pass my URL and concatenate with "?page=", so I can't pass the entire list.
I already tried to make a for loop, but without success.
Anyone does how can I make the pagination work for both pages?

Here is my code for now:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'QuotesSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://PageDucky.com', 'https://PageHorse.com']
    categories = []
    count = 1

    def parse(self, response):

        # Get categories
        urli = response.url
        QuotesSpider.categories = urli[urli.find('/browse')+7:].split('/')
        QuotesSpider.categories.pop(0)
        
         
        #GET ITEMS PER PAGE AND CALC THE PAGINATION
        items = int(response.xpath(
                '*//div[@id="body"]/div/label[@class="item-count"]/text()').get().replace(' items', ''))
        pages = items / 10
        
        #CALL THE OTHER DEF TO READ THE PAGE ITSELF
        for i in response.css('div#body div a::attr(href)').getall():
            if i[:5] == '/item':
                yield scrapy.Request('http://mainpage' + i, callback=self.parseobj)
        
        #HERE IS THE PROBLEM, I TESTED AND WITHOUT FOR LOOP WORKS FOR ONE URL ONLY
        for y in QuotesSpider.start_urls:
            if pages >= QuotesSpider.count:
                next_page = y + '?page=' + str(QuotesSpider.count)
                QuotesSpider.count = QuotesSpider.count + 1
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever website you're scraping, find the xpath/css location where the 'next page' button is. Get the href of that, and yield your next request to that link.

Alternatively you don't need to use start_urls if you write your own start_requests function, where you can put custom logic inside of it, like looping through your desired urls and appendimng the correct page number to each. See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use "href". But I already figured it out. I will update with my solution. I'm now facing another problem. My spider stops at ending of first link, she not follow the others in list... I will create a new post for it. Could you help me?

Comment: Sure, shoot me a message.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

I can't use "href" because isn't the same link, for example the page 01 was 'https:pageducky.com' and the page 02 was 'https:duckyducky.com?page=2'

So I use `response.url` and manipulate the string considering the `?page=`... something like that:

```
resp1 = response.url[:response.url.find('?page=')]
resp = resp1 + '?page=' + str(QuotesSpider.count)
```